Phalasruti of the mantra om mahasaraswati namah
What are the phalasruti of the mantra om mahasaraswatya namaha? Is it the same as om saraswatya namaha?
Does the given mantra give any help to gain wisdom , intelligence and knowledge regarding any physical sciences like maths , physics , economics etc ?
Also does this mantras help to burn our bad karmas gradually that we have accumulated throughout our lifetimes?

I) Your first question What are the phalasruti of the mantra "om mahasaraswatya namaha"? Is it the same as "om saraswatya namaha"?
Yes, both om mahasaraswatya namaha(ॐ महासरस्वत्यै नमः) and om saraswatya namaha(ॐ सरस्वत्यै नमः) are one and the same but please know that they are not Moola Mantra of Sri Saraswati Devatha.
II) Your second question Does the given mantra give any help to gain wisdom , intelligence and knowledge regarding any physical sciences like maths , physics , economics etc?
Either phalasruti or reciting this mantra daily will definitely yield the blessing of Sri Saraswati Devatha Who bestows all kinds of Vidya. This blessing will make you focus in your studies resulting in better results.

If your are running Dasha is either Mercury or Jupiter in your
Horoscope, then the result will be the best such as becoming a rank
student.

iii) Your third and final question Also does this mantras help to burn our bad karmas gradually that we have accumulated throughout our lifetimes?
Answer is No.
Suppose you recite this manta daily at the same time you commit a lot of selfish and nefarious acts, then how does this mantra capable of burning out seeds of accumulated bad karma?

For that, you need to practice Ashtānga Yoga(अष्टाङ्ग योग/Eight-limbed
Union) in order to burn the seeds of accumulated bad karma in Causal Body(Kārana Sarīra/कारण शरीर).

Yoga Sūtras(योग सूत्र) Authored by Maharishi Patanjali(महऋषि पतञ्जलि) consists of 196 Sūtras (written in Sanskrit Language) which are divided in to 4 Pādas(पाद/Quarter) as follows:

Samādhi Pāda(समाधि/Absorbed in Concentration): This chapter deals with the Union of the Subject(the meditator) and the Object (of meditation). Maharishi Patanjali answers, using 51 Sūtras in this chapter, the question What is Yoga?
Sādhana Pāda (साधना/Practice): This chapter deals with the Philosophy of Klesa(क्लेश/Affliction/Hindrance/Grief) while attempting to answer in 55 sūtras Why should anyone practice Yoga?
Vibhūdi Pāda (विभूति/Superhuman Powers): This chapter deals with the accomplishment of Super Powers as result of Samādhi(समाधि) in 56 Sūtras.
Kailvalya Pāda (कैवल्य/Enlightenment/Emancipation): This chapter deals with, using 34 Sūtras, the detachment of the soul(पुरुष/Purusha/Atman) from matter(प्रकृति/Prakruti) or further transmigration(Cycle of Birth).


It is mandatory to study Yoga Sūtras to learn about Yoga,
Meditation and the supernatural powers associated with Mind.

What is Ashtānga Yoga(अष्टाङ्ग योग/Eight-limbed Union)?
Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Philosophy(योग तत्व) is divided in to Eight Limbs also known as Ashtānga Yoga. The term Astānga is compound word which is Ashta(अष्ट/Eight) + Anga(अङ्ग/Limb/Component). These eight limbs are nothing but eight rungs of a ladder which Yogi climbs up to reach Kailvalya (कैवल्य/Enlightenment) and are explained below:

Yama(यम/Restraint/தள்ளல்): The Self-Restraint eliminates disturbances caused by the uncontrolled emotions and desires. The practice of restraint is moral which are: (i) Ahimsa: do not kill or injure any being. Be kind to all (ii) Speak and act truth, (iii) Steal not, nor acquire illicit gains, (iv) Practice continence and celibacy and (v) Be not avaricious. Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-II, Sūtras 30–31 for more details.
Niyama(नियम/Observance/கொள்ளல்): The Fixed-Observances eliminates disturbances caused by the uncontrolled emotions and desires. Observances are five-fold which are (i) Be clean in body and mind (ii) Be contented (iii) Practice asceticism and austerity (vi) Study sacred books and (v) Be devoted to God. Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-II, Sūtras 32–45 for more details.
Āsana(आसन/Posture): The Posture eliminates disturbances arising from physical body. Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-II, Sūtras 46–48 for more details. International Day of Yoga, or commonly and unofficially referred to as Yoga Day, is celebrated annually on 21 June since its inception in 2015. An international day for yoga was declared unanimously by the United Nations General Assembly (UNGA). Yoga is a physical, mental and spiritual practice originated in India which is now promoted by World Body.
Prānāyāma(प्राणायामम्/Breath Extension): The Regulation of Breath eliminates disturbances arising from breath. Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-II, Sūtras 49–53 for more details.
Pratyāhāram(प्रत्याहारम्/Withdrawal): By detaching the sense organs from mind, Pratyāhāra cuts off the external world and impressions which it produces on the mind. Thus the mind is completely isolated from the external world. Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-II, Sūtras 54–55 for more details.
Dhārana(धारणा/Fixity): The Confining of Mind within a limited mental area which is the object of concentration is known as Dhārana(धारणा). Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-III, Sūtra-1 for more details.
Dyāna(ध्यान/Contemplation): Uninterrupted flow of the mind towards the object (chosen for meditation) is called Dyāna(ध्यान). Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-III, Sūtra-2 for more details.
Samādhi(समाधि/Concentration): While contemplating (ध्यान/Dyana) there is not only the consciousness of the object of mediation but also the presence of mental self-awareness. i.e. the mind itself is preventing the realization of the very essence of the object of mediation. When Dyāna culminates to a state where there is complete freedom from both distractions and self-awareness and the object of meditation alone remains in the field of consciousness, it is called Samādhi(समाधि). Refer Maharishi Patanjali’s Yoga Sūtra Ch-III, Sūtra-3 for more details.

While practicing Yoga, an aspirant gains extraordinary super powers, called Ashta Siddh produced as Side Effects. i.e. aspirant gains or accomplishes these powers spontaneously whether he desires them or not.
Conclusion:

Just observe the first two rungs of Ashtānga Yoga, viz., Yama
(यम/Restraint/தள்ளல்) and Niyama(नियम/Observance/கொள்ளல்) which are
capable of burning out seeds of your bad karmas accumulated in Causal Body(Kārana Sarīra/कारण शरीर/காரண சரீரம்)!

Good Luck!

I would like to get any scriptural reference to point number 2 that Saraswati maa will grant that intelligence knowledge and wisdom of our chosen subjects. In general we hear people say that Saraswati is the deity of knowledge and wisdom but I want to verify that this specific mantra will give me what I want. Thank you.

@Sillyasker what do you mean by scriptural reference? Do you want quotes exclusively from Veda/Upanishad? Please be specific. Thanks.

by scriptural reference I mean any text that specifically mentions that it will provide buddhi ,gyan ,smriti, Kalpana Shakti.

@Sillyasker Refer Sri Saraswati stotram (श्री सरस्वती स्तोत्रम्‌ ) by Sage Agastya and Sarasvati-rahasya Upanishad(सरस्वती रहस्य उपनिषत्) one of the eight Shakta Upanishads and embedded in the Krishna Yajurveda.

@Sillyasker Link to Sri Saraswati stotram:  https://greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/saraswati_stotram.php

@Sillyasker  Here is a link to Sarasvati-rahasya Upanishad : https://www.celextel.org/upanishads-krishna-yajur-veda/sarasvati-rahasya-upanishad/

@Sillyasker Here is Wikipedia link to Sarasvati-rahasya Upanishad: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarasvati-rahasya_Upanishad

@Sillyasker There is Adhi Sankara's "Sharada Bhujangam" which is one of the most cherished Sri Saraswati Devatha Stotram whose link is  https://www.greenmesg.org/stotras/saraswati/sharada_bhujangam.php

@Sillyasker If you are interested to pursue Sri Saraswati Devatha in Tantra Margam(तन्त्र मार्गम्) in order to accomplish Mantra Siddhi(मन्त्र सिद्ध), then read my Quora Post: https://www.quora.com/What-is-Sri-V%C4%81geeswar%C4%AB-Tantra-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0-or/answer/Krishna-Joshiar
